# "Can't Buy With This Account" POST Request Error When Using The Buys Endpoint To Buy Bitcoin

Tags: node.js, typescript, axios, coinbase-api

My goal is to try and get a Node app (written in Typescript) to buy bitcoin using my "GBP Wallet" (fiat account). I am currently trying this via using the Axios library, rather than any unofficial Coinbase client libraries out there. I am successfully able to get data that I need from the GET endpoints of the Coinbase API. However, with the following POST endpoint I get an error:

`POST https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/buys`

The error:

`[ { id: 'invalid_request', message: "Can't buy with this account" } ]`

Here is a simplified example of the code I am trying to run at the moment:

```js
import * as crypto from 'crypto';
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, Method } from 'axios';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

const timer = (ms: number) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

function isNumeric(str: string): boolean {
  const noSpacesStr = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
  return !isNaN(Number(noSpacesStr)) && noSpacesStr.length !== 0;
}

async function coinbaseApiRequest(url: string, method: Method, data?: any): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  if (process.env.COINBASE_API_KEY === undefined || process.env.COINBASE_API_SECRET === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Missing credentials');
  }
  const stringData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const message = data === undefined ? timestamp.toString() + method + url : timestamp.toString() + method + url + stringData;
  const signature = crypto.createHmac("sha256", process.env.COINBASE_API_SECRET).update(message).digest("hex");

  const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method,
    url: `https://api.coinbase.com${url}`,
    headers: {
      'CB-ACCESS-SIGN': signature,
      'CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP': timestamp,
      'CB-ACCESS-KEY': process.env.COINBASE_API_KEY,
      'CB-VERSION': '2021-05-19',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data
  };

  return axios(config);
}

async function getBuyPrice(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return coinbaseApiRequest('/v2/prices/BTC-GBP/buy', 'GET');
}

async function getSellPrice(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return coinbaseApiRequest('/v2/prices/BTC-GBP/sell', 'GET');
}

async function getGBPAccount(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return coinbaseApiRequest('/v2/accounts/GBP', 'GET');
}

async function getBitcoinAccount(): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  return coinbaseApiRequest('/v2/accounts/BTC', 'GET');
}

async function getGBPWalletPaymentMethodID(): Promise<string> {
  const paymentMethods = await coinbaseApiRequest('/v2/payment-methods', 'GET');

  for (let i = 0; i < paymentMethods.data.data.length; i++) {
    const paymentMethod = paymentMethods.data.data[i];
    if (paymentMethod.name === 'GBP Wallet' && paymentMethod.type === 'fiat_account') {
      return paymentMethod.id;
    }
  }

  throw new Error('GBP wallet has not been found');
}

async function postBuyBitcoin(accountId: string, amount: string, paymentMethod: string): Promise<AxiosResponse> {
  if (!isNumeric(amount)) { throw new Error('amount arg is not a valid number'); }
  const body = { amount, currency: 'BTC', payment_method: paymentMethod };
  return coinbaseApiRequest(`/v2/accounts/${accountId}/buys`, 'POST', body);
}

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  try {
    const oldGBPAccRes = await getGBPAccount();
    const oldBTCAccRes = await getBitcoinAccount();
    const paymentMethodID = await getGBPWalletPaymentMethodID();

    const buyRes = await postBuyBitcoin(oldGBPAccRes.data.data.id, '0.00001', paymentMethodID);
      
    const newGBPAccRes = await getGBPAccount();
    const newBTCAccRes = await getBitcoinAccount();

    console.log(`old GBP account response:`);
    console.log(oldGBPAccRes.data);
    console.log(`old BTC account response:`);
    console.log(oldBTCAccRes.data);
    console.log(`bitcoin buy response:`);
    console.log(buyRes);
    console.log(`new GBP account response:`);
    console.log(newGBPAccRes.data);
    console.log(`new BTC account response:`);
    console.log(newBTCAccRes.data);

    console.log('Finished payment');
  } catch (error: any | AxiosError) {
      if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
        console.log(error.response?.data.errors);
      }
  }
}

run();
```

All the GET request functions seem to work fine and return the responses correctly when I run them individually. The only issue I have is with the POST request function. I get the following error logged when running the code above:

`[ { id: 'invalid_request', message: "Can't buy with this account" } ]`

Not sure why this is happening, and there does not seem to be much on this online relevant to node based implementations, but [this](https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-python/issues/58) seems to be somewhat related. would appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"This repository has been archived by the owner. It is now read-only."* -- The whole thing looks pretty dodgy, IMO.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Please don't comment if you have nothing useful to say.

Comment: Useful is in the eye of the beholder, I suppose.  How much risk do you incur by attempting to use a library with known problems that's not currently supported by anyone, especially when currency is involved?

Comment: I am not using any libraries with known problems. I believe you are referring to https://github.com/coinbase/coinbase-node, which I havn't used for that very reason. I am simply making my own requests via axios by referring to the coinbase API docs.